# Content of the table disappears after filtration

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I need to pass filtration from configuration file to datatable. When the table is rendered the user must be able to clean the filtration and see the full content of the table

The problem arises when the filtration is applied to factor columns. In this case the content of the table is rendered but is not shown in the table. It is necessary click additionally on the filter and choose another value. But it still works fine with character columns. How one may fix it?

There is an example which reproduce my problem.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    selectInput(inputId = "table_fltration", 
                label = 'Choose table filtration', 
                choices = c("Working example",
                            "Not working example"), 
                selected = "Working example"),

    actionButton(inputId = 'update_btn', label = "Use config")),

  fluidRow(dataTableOutput("iris_table"))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  columns_search <- reactive({

    if (input$table_fltration == "Working example") {
      ex <- c("7.2 ... 7.9", "", "", "", "", "[\"anything\"]")
    } else {
      ex <- c("", "", "", "", "[\"anything\"]", "")
    }


    columns_search <- list()

    for ( i in 1:length(ex)) {

      if(ex[i] != "") {
        element = list(list(search = ex[i]))
      } else {element = NULL}

      columns_search[i] <- element
    }

    columns_search

  })

  iris_table_ex <- reactive({

    iris$Species_2 = as.character(iris$Species)
    iris

  })

  observeEvent(input$update_btn, 

               output$iris_table <- DT::renderDataTable({

                 DT::datatable(iris_table_ex(), 
                               filter = list(position = 'top'),
                               class = 'hover',
                               rownames = FALSE,
                               options = list(orderClasses = TRUE,
                                              stateSave = FALSE,
                                              searchHighlight = TRUE,
                                              searchCols = columns_search(),
                                              scrollX = TRUE,
                                              paging = TRUE,
                                              pageLength = 10))
               })
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: When there is not a match, what do you expect to see

Comment: I expect to see nothing. But I still want to clear the filtration in table and see its full content.

Comment: Maybe the solution from this post can be applied here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108515/r-shiny-display-full-dataframe-without-filter-input-until-filterinputs-are-chang